# Cloud Functions get list from Realtime Database path

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm trying to retrieve a list of objects from a path. The document structure is shown below:

```
-- device
    |
    -- {id}
        |
        ...
        -- user:
            |
            -- {pushId}: <user id x>
            |
            ...
            |
            -- {pushId}: <user id z>
    |
    ...
|
```

The code below is how I'm trying to get all user IDs, but I'm not getting a list, only getting the snapshot.

```
const getUserIdsPromise = admin.database().ref(dbVersionRef + `/device/${id}/user/{pushId}`).once('value');
return Promise.all([anotherPromise, getUserIdsPromise]).then((results) => {
    const userIds = results[1].child();

    // No id is logged
    userIds.forEach((id) => {
        debug.log('userId: ' + id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading `/device/${id}/user/{pushId}`, which means that you're reading a single user.

If you want to get all users for a single device, you should read from `/device/${id}/user`:

```
admin.database().ref(dbVersionRef + `/device/${id}/user/`)
     .once('value')
     .then((results) => {
       results.forEach((snapshot) => {
         debug.log('userId: ' + snapshot.val());
       })
     });
```

If you want to get devices, you should read from `/device`.

Comment: Thanks, man! I got a little confused about the context params, but your response cleared a lot!